# Remove 'Publish to Facebook' checkbox for Facebook page publish plugin

Tags: plugins, facebook

I am using Facebook Page Publish plugin and it adds a checkbox within the metabox submitdiv. I would like to remove that checkbox for my custom post type. Is there any way to do that using a function?

This is the function from Facebook Page Publish that is printing the checkbox:

```
/**
 * Renders a 'publish to facebook' checkbox. Renders the box only if 
 * the current post is a real post, not a page or something else.
 */
 function fpp_render_post_button() {
    global $post;

    $object_access_token = get_option('fpp_object_access_token');

    if (!array_pop(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_fpp_is_published'))) {
            echo '<label for="fpp_post_to_facebook"><img style="vertical-align:middle; margin:2px" src="'.FPP_BASE_URL.'publish_icon.png" alt="'.__('Publish to Facebook', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN).'" /> '.__('Publish to Facebook', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN).' </label><input '.(((FPP_DEFAULT_POST_TO_FACEBOOK or fpp_get_default_publishing($post)) and !empty($object_access_token)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').' type="checkbox" value="1" id="fpp_post_to_facebook" name="fpp_post_to_facebook" '.(empty($object_access_token) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '').' />';
    } else {
            echo '<label for="fpp_post_to_facebook"><img style="vertical-align:middle; margin:2px" src="'.FPP_BASE_URL.'publish_icon.png" alt="'.__('Publish to Facebook', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN).'" /> '.__('Post <em>again</em> to Facebook', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN).' </label><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="fpp_post_to_facebook" name="fpp_post_to_facebook" '.(empty($object_access_token) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '').' />';
    }
    if (empty($object_access_token)) {
            echo '<div><em style="color:#aa6600">'.sprintf(__('Facebook Page Publish is not set up.<br />Please check your <a href="%s">plugin settings</a>.', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN), 'options-general.php?page='.plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'</em></div>';
    }
    if ($post->post_status == "private") {
            echo '<div><em style="color:#aa6600">'.__('Private posts are not published', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN).'</em></div>';
    }
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="fpp_send_from_admin" value="1" />';

    $error = get_option('fpp_error');
    if (!empty($error)) {
            echo '<div class="error"><strong>'.sprintf(__('Your Facebook Page Publish plugin reports an error. Please check your <a href="%s">plugin settings</a>.', FPP_TEXT_DOMAIN), 'options-general.php?page='.plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'</strong></div>';
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is used to render button and it's called inside `fpp_post_submitbox_start_action()`, which does some conditional check and is hooked into `post_submitbox_start` action.

First you need to remove plugins original action and use your own with conditional to render button. See code example below.

```
// Remove original action
remove_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'fpp_post_submitbox_start_action' );

/**
 * Renders Facebook publish button, if post type is 'post'
 * and current user has 'publish_posts' capability.
 */
function mamaduka_post_submitbox_start() {
    global $post;

    if ( 'post' == get_post_type( $post ) && current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
        fpp_render_post_button();

}
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'mamaduka_post_submitbox_start' );
```

To remove check box only from specific custom post type you can change conditional post type check, like so:

```
if ( 'myposttype' != get_post_type( $post ) && current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
```

Comment: Do I actually need the current_user_can() check? I would like to remove it for any user.

Comment: Sure you can remove it, but no one can publish posts without that capability.